# Custom File Version/ Product Version of exe by building an application

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-numbers

As the title suggests I need to assign an application a custom file and/or product version by building a project from Visual Studio.

I know you can assign a build number from an application publish but I am not publishing these applications, I am simply building "release" files.

Is there a way within Visual Studio to specify these file versions before I build the application?

Thanks in advance!

[image: App Properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way within Visual Studio to specify these file versions before I build the application?

Yes, you can specify File/Product version by `AssemblyInfo.cs` before you build the application.

**First**, the File version looks for the attribute `AssemblyFileVersion` in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. So you can specify the File version by setting the value `AssemblyFileVersion`. I change the `AssemblyFileVersion` value from `1.0.0.0` to `2.0.0.0`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2.0.0.0")]
```

**Second**, ProductVersion first looks to see if the assembly containing the main
executable has the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute on it. If this
attribute exists, it is used for Product Version.
If this attribute does not exist, both properties use the `AssemblyFileVersion` instead.

So, in your project, open the AssemblyInfo.cs file. In this file, I added a
line like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("4.0.0.0")]
```

Then after build is complete. The file version is `2.0.0.0` and the product version is `4.0.0.0`.